# Run saving user function only after google authentication callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have built a google authentication in React + Firebase. Successfully, I added this feature but currently this calls `firebase.auth().getRedirectResult()` every time when they come to home. I want to call this **only after google authentication callback**.

```
class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      user: null
    };
  }

  async componentWillMount() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      this.setState({ user });

      if (user) {
        this.props.history.push("/user/settings");
      }
    });

    // Want to call this only after google authentication callback
    firebase
      .auth()
      .getRedirectResult()
      .then(result => {
        if (result.credential) {
          var token = result.credential.accessToken;
          console.log("token", token);
        }
        var user = result.user;
        this.props.createUser(user);
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("error", error);
      });

  onLogin = () => {
    const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);
  };

  render() {
    return (
　　　// Signin with Google
      <button className="btn btnPrimary" onClick={this.onLogin}>
        <span>Google Signin</span>
      </button>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps({ user }) {
  return { user: user };
}
```

Comment: How do you indicate you've been redirected after a Google login? Is there perhaps a query string parameters you could leverage? Or would it maybe be fair to say if `user` isn't set then run the code?

Comment: Authenticate with Google by clicking `onLogin`. And then you can see Google Login page. This app registers `createUser(user)`(this is Redux code, and it works). The matter is that the login page and callback page are in the same component... I don't want run `firebase.auth().getRedirectResult()` for users who just visit this page.

Answer (score 0):

I set `firebase.auth().getRedirectResult()` into `if (user) { }`.

like this:

```
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      this.setState({ user });

      if (user) {
        this.props.history.push("/user/settings");
    firebase
      .auth()
      .getRedirectResult()
      .then(result => {
        if (result.credential) {
          var token = result.credential.accessToken;
          console.log("token", token);
        }
        var user = result.user;
        this.props.createUser(user);
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("error", error);
      });
      }
    });
```